# DNS that resolves to localhost doesn't respond to ping

Tags: websocket, dns, localhost, ping

We have an app that uses web sockets running on a Windows 10 machine. We also have a DNS entry (test.company.com for example) that's set to resolve to 127.0.0.1 (as the app is running on localhost).

The other end of the web socket handshake is opened by browsing to a specific web page which then attempts to connect to the app using new WebSocket(ws://test.company.com:8500);

70% of the time this works and everything is good. Some users have trouble. We asked them to ping test.company.com and it comes back with Ping request could not find host. So, the connection fails. If they use new WebSocket(ws://127.0.0.1:8500) it works just fine.

Why do some environments not resolve the domain name?